Is it possible to calculate the (blockchain) network congestion?
Been trying to understand how to calculate blockchain's network congestion. (using web3js)
But I can't actually figure it out. The values I'm getting are way different than the value of network congestion provided by Infura's Gas Api.
async function calculateNetworkCongestion(blocksToAnalyze = 10) {
  const latestBlockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();

  let totalGasUsed = BigInt(0);
  let totalGasLimit = BigInt(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < blocksToAnalyze; i++) {
    const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(Number(latestBlockNumber) - i);
    totalGasUsed += BigInt(block.gasUsed);
    totalGasLimit += BigInt(block.gasLimit);
  }

  const averageGasUsed = Number(totalGasUsed) / blocksToAnalyze;
  const averageGasLimit = Number(totalGasLimit) / blocksToAnalyze;

  const congestionRatio = averageGasUsed / averageGasLimit;

  return congestionRatio;
}

I know it's not even close to the solution and that is exactly why  I'm here.
